# Unable to create AKS Cluster using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

I created a resource group using CLI and did not get any error however running the below command from the same blog I keep getting the same error.

```
az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --node-count 2 --generate-ssh-keys
```

**`Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4`**

I tried executing this command multiple times via windows cmd or even VS Code terminal

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score -1):

**Possible Solutions:**

- Please Check the resource group exists before creating the cluster.
- Please move the **id_rsa** and **id_rsa.pub** files under **~/.ssh** folder to a different location and try running the command from Azure CLI again.
- The error may also occur due to quota for the subscription . Request support for quota increase for your subscription.To request a quota increase, go to the portal and file a support issue. In the support issue, request an increase in your quota for the region into which you want to deploy.
  The step by step instructions for creating a support issue are provided here: [Quota errors - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-resource-quota#solution)

> Quotas are applied per resource group, subscriptions, accounts, and
> other scopes. For example, your subscription may be configured to
> limit the number of cores for a region. If you attempt to deploy a
> virtual machine with more cores than the permitted amount, you receive
> an error stating the quota has been exceeded. For complete quota
> information [see Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and
> constraints.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits)